# Break line using Flex keeping elements centered

Tags: html, css, flexbox

This is another CSS Flex question, I'm sorry but I've been struggling a lot using Flex, I'm trying to make a kind of slider, in which it will have a left and right arrow and elements in between, like so:

[image: Flex-el]

The problem I'm facing is that in certain number of elements I need to break a line, keeping the alignment center both vertically and horizontally, like this: (paint pro editing)

[image: Flex-2]

I can't find a way to do this, I'm lost.

This is my actual code for the first image:

HMTL:

```
<div class="main allin">
  <div class="left-arrow">
    <i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_left</i>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-con ">
    <div class="item-1">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" />
    </div>

    <div class="item-2">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" />
    </div>

    <div class="item-3">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" />
    </div>

  </div>
    <div class="right-arrow">
      <i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_right</i>
  </div>

  </div>

  <div class="main break">
  <div class="left-arrow">
    <i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_left</i>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.main{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
}

.flex-con{
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.flex-con div{
  padding:20px;
}
```

And this is a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/elunap/pen/wZpXGm)

How can I achieve this? thanks.

Comment: use flex-wrap:wrap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put all your `item-x` elements within the same `flex-con` wrapper.
Then, simply add the following properties:

```
flex-wrap: wrap; // to wrap its children into multiple lines
justify-content: center; // to center horizontally
```

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.flex-con {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-con div {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/material-design-icons/3.0.1/iconfont/material-icons.min.css" />

<div class="main break">
  <div class="left-arrow">
    <i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_left</i>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-con ">
    <div class="item-1">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" />
    </div>
    <div class="item-2">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" />
    </div>
    <div class="item-3">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" />
    </div>
    <div class="item-4">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" />
    </div>
    <div class="item-5">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-arrow">
    <i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_right</i>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Click **Full page** for better demonstration.